# ASP.NET inline code iif

Tags: asp.net, inline, iif

I have the following code:

```
<%# IIf(IsDBNull(Container.DataItem("idQuestionaire")), Me.pnlAdd.Visible = True, Me.pnlRemove.Visible = True)%> 

<asp:Panel ID="pnlAdd" runat="server" Visible="false">
        add
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlRemove" runat="server" Visible="false">
        remove
</asp:Panel>
```

So I want that if the Container item is NULL that the "pnlAdd" is Visible.

But I get the following error:

> pnlAdd is not member of mySite.aspx

Comment: check your file name, did you rename or move it? check/post your first line of .aspx here, check/post your class name in the code behind here?

Comment: Did you try shifting `IIf` below the panels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

I used this code:

```
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAdd" runat="server"  Text="::Add" Visible='<%# IIf(IsDBNull(Container.DataItem("idQuestionaire")), "true", "false")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnRemove" runat="server"  Text="::Remove" Visible='<%# IIf(IsDBNull(Container.DataItem("idQuestionaire")), "false", "true")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the context isn't correct, not sure if you can do this type of thing from within a data-binding expression. Try setting it by directly embedding it in the markup e.g.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlAdd" runat="server" Visible="<%# IsDBNull(Container.DataItem("idQuestionairre")) %>">
    add
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlAdd" runat="server" Visible="<%# !IsDBNull(Container.DataItem("idQuestionairre")) %>">
    remove
</asp:Panel>
```